# how to know the currently online user in .net

Tags: .net, meta-tags

I want to know the currently online users who are using my website.
I know I can do it by using session variables but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

When user logs in, write it into the database. If you are using ASP.NET membership provider, that info is already written in the aspnet_Users table. You can then just query the database to check for all the logged in users.